# Converting localtime to time_t (C++)

Tags: c++, date, time, localtime, time-t

I creating date() function on C++ http://aliarth.lt/date.cpp and I got one problem with `localtome_to_time()` conversion. Does anyone know how that local_time variable:

```
int time_integer = 12345;
time_t time = (time_t)time_integer;

tm *local_time = localtime(&time);
local_time->tm_year = 100;
local_time->tm_mon = 10;
local_time->tm_mday = 1;
```

Convert to `time_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`mktime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/), here is its signature:

```
time_t mktime (struct tm * timeptr);
```

> Returns the value of type `time_t` that represents the local time described by the `tm` structure pointed by `timeptr` (which may be modified).